Unable to get data from getServerSession(), But able to get from the useSession() in next-auth
I am using nextAuth as the authentication management and I am able to get data response via useSession() hook but when I tried to do this for getServerSession() I am getting null on the page. But in the network tab I am able to see the data of session.
This is my /app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export const handler = NextAuth({
    providers:[
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Email",
            credentials:{
                username: {label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "Username"},
                password: {label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "Password"}
            },
            async authorize(credentials: any){

                console.log(credentials)

                return {
                    id: "user1",
                    name: "Jitesh Rajoriya",
                    email: "rajoriya@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
})

export const GET = handler;
export const POST = handler;

and this is my /app/user/page.tsx
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { handler } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

async function getUser() {
    const session = await getServerSession(handler);
    return session;
  }

export default async function(){
    const session = await getUser();
    
    return <div>
        {JSON.stringify(session)}
    </div>
}

This is my .env file
NEXTAUTH_URL = http://localhost:3000 NEXTAUTH_SECRET = mysecretpassword_nextauth
and I am getting this
enter image description here In this image you can see that the data is available in the response but not on the page.
I am expecting that the problem might be in the component that how I am rendering it. Or maybe problem in the version of nextAuth and NextJS
